# Where is CAN ID in CAN Message Frame

Tags: can-bus

I am new to the CAN-BUS protocol. So was going through the CAN Bus Specifications and related documents.

I have always used the CAN ID and Frame at the application level.
CANID like 0x1a1 CAN Frame like ff 22 ff 33 co 33 ee 44 (8 bytes).
In the specification, they mentioned that the Frame consists of identifier field.
I doubt what is that.
Is that the CAN ID like 0x1a1 or CAN ID + some other stuff.
No documents mentioned that clearly.
If that is not CAN ID.. Where is CAN-ID in CAN Format.

Can anyone clarify that doubt?

Answer (score 1):

In short, a single CAN message consists of CANID, the CAN data and other stuffs,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Data_frame